# What is the best approach for Spring Cloud Logging?

Tags: logging, log4j2, spring-cloud

I am running Spring Boot Application as Systemd service on AWS. As a result all log messages go to system.log together with Linux log messages and that makes log is hard to read.

What is best approach to not flood system.log and keep separate log per application/micro-service? Is it Log4j 2? Could you please recommend alternatives?

Comment: I would suggest ELK logger. Which logs all your log.info to kibana as a microservice.

Comment: thanks @Jesse, at this point I ended up with ELK stack + FileBeat plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [LogStash](https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/) and [spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth),
This provides greater stability and easy accessing of logs.

Zipkin also allows you to trace your request propagation to multiple microservices using trace-id and span-id.

Using Logstash you can log the logs using different format(JSON or plaintext).

Then configure your logs to [gray-log](https://objectpartners.com/2016/05/04/graylog-with-spring-boot-open-source-log-and-event-analysis/) and [sentry](http://www.jjoe64.com/2016/03/integrate-sentry-in-spring-boot.html), spring-boot provides supports to both.

In this way you can easily access organise and access your logs.This also provides a segregation of system.log and linux.log

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I think this is nice approach long-term, but for now I decided to use only ELK and left sleuth/zipkin for later since request tracing is not the highest priority. Maybe my approach will save someone some time: 1. Switched logging from console to file in Spring Boot. That prevents syslog flooding. 2. Installed Filebeat on same server and configured it to send logs to another server. 3. On that 2nd server installed ELK and configured Logstash to receive logs from Filebeat. This looks like pretty basic approach.